# Node.js Apple Pay - "unsupported" error when validating merchant on server

Tags: node.js, ssl, applepay

I have a Node.js application that starts an Apple Pay session by validating a merchant. When running this application locally, everything works fine. However, when I deploy it to the Railway.app platform, I'm encountering an "unsupported" error which appears to be related to the TLS/SSL configuration.

Here is the key portion of my code:

```js
async function validateMerchant() {
  let response = {}

  const certFilePath = './merchent_certificate/Certificates.p12'

  const cert = fs.readFileSync(certFilePath)

  try {
    const options = {
      url: 'https://apple-pay-gateway.apple.com/paymentservices/startSession',
      agentOptions: {
        pfx: cert,
        passphrase: '********',
      },
      method: 'post',
      body: {
        merchantIdentifier: 'merchant.com.zeebuz.pay',
        displayName: 'Your Store Name',
        initiative: 'web',
        initiativeContext: 'dev-app.zeebuz.com',
      },
      json: true,
    }
    response = await promisifyRequest(options)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
  return response
}
```

(Note: The actual passphrase is replaced by '*' for security reasons.)

The exact error message is:

```
Error: unsupported
at configSecureContext (node:internal/tls/secure-context:277:15)
at Object.createSecureContext (node:_tls_common:121:3)
at Object.connect (node:_tls_wrap:1630:48)
at Agent.createConnection (node:https:147:22)
at Agent.createSocket (node:_http_agent:347:26)
at Agent.addRequest (node:_http_agent:294:10)
at new ClientRequest (node:_http_client:335:16)
at Object.request (node:https:357:10)
at Request.start (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:751:32)
at Request.write (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1491:10)
```

The certificate and private key were generated on my local machine following the Apple Pay guidelines and the PKCS12 certificate is stored in the file 'Certificates.p12'.

I'm wondering if the certificate creation location could be causing this issue, even though it seems unlikely.

Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else encounters this issue, the solution was to convert the p12 to a single pem (that includes both the cert and the key), and to modify the agentOptions

```js
agentOptions: {
  cert: pemFile
  key: pemFile
}
```